# How can I command my bot to lock the current channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to be able to lock down a channel when I use a command. This is my current code:

```js
if (command === 'lock') {
 guild.members.cache.find.permissions.remove('SEND_MESSAGES');
}
```

However, it's not working, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The small snippet of code is a good start but it would be more helpful if you provided more context and relevant code to the issue you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

The `.updateOverwrite()` method will update an existing permission setting or create one if none exists. This is how you use it:

```
.updateOverwrite(userOrRole, options, [reason])
```

> `Role`: RoleResolveable (role object) or [Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake),
> `User`: UserResolveble (user object) or [Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake)
> `Reason`: String (optional)

Example of how you could use this:

```
// First find the role we want to overwrite permissions for
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone");

message.channel.updateOverwrite(role, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }, `Overwrite permissions`)
.then(() => console.log("Permissions overwritten."))
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Oh no! Something went wrong! " + error.message);
});
```

If you want to overwrite all channels, simply map all channels in the guild and use `channel.updateOverwrite()`. You want to use `updateOverwrite` since `overwritePermissions` will replace all current permissions and replace it with the one you want to add or update.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need [`message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) to get the channel the command is sent in. Then, you can use [`channel.updateOverwrite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite):

```js
// fun fact, the @everyone role shares the same id as the guild
message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
   SEND_MESSAGES: false // cannot send messages
}, 'Channel Lockdown')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(consol.error); // handle any errors
```

---

The `updateOverwrite()` function accepts three parameters. First, a `User` or `Role` resolvable (typically the ID or object). In this case, I used `message.guild.id`, which is the ID of the @everyone role.

Then, the overwrite options. You can use any [Permission Flag](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) (for example, `ADD_REACTIONS`, and `VIEW_CHANNEL`) followed by `false` for denied, `null` for unset, and `true` for allowed.

Then finally, you can provide a reason which is what will appear in the audit logs!

---

You can do something similarly if you want to lockdown *every* channel:

```js
// iterate a function over every channel in the guild
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
  message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
    SEND_MESSAGES: false
  }, 'Channel Lockdown')
   .then(console.log)
   .catch(consol.error);
});
```

---

#### This will work the same with `v11.x`, just replace `updateOverwrite()` with [`overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions)

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know about that one!

Comment: Yeah, it's a very useful trick 

Comment: ```if(command === "lock") {
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone");

message.channel.updateOverwrite(role, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }, `Overwrite permissions`)
.then(() => console.log("Permissions overwritten."))
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Oh no! Something went wrong! " + error.message);
});```
============================================

 ```if(command === "lock") {
message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
   SEND_MESSAGES: false // cannot send messages
}, 'Channel Lockdown')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(consol.error);
}```

Comment: I tried the both scripts
there was no error but nothing worked

Comment: What version of `discord.js` are you using?

Comment: I think    "discord.js": "^11.6.3",

Comment: That would do it. We're both offering fixes for `^12.x`. I'll try to edit my answer with a `v11` method.

Comment: Alright, that was easier than I thought. Just replace `updateOverwrite()` with `overwritePermissions()`. Everything else can stay the same.

Comment: `.cache` isn't implemented in **v11** only in **v12** @PROTHEPRO if you want to use `.cache` property, upgrade your discord.js depenency.

Comment: Just to make sure, what does `npm view discord.js version` return in terminal?

Comment: its all ok now
I made my own command and it worked!!!!